# как вытащить из файла определенные данные

Tags: bash, shell

в файле **wp-config.php** есть такие строки

```
    /** MySQL database username */
    define( 'DB_USER', 'root' );

    /** MySQL database password */
    define( 'DB_PASSWORD', 'passs' );
```

мне нужно записать в переменные эти данные **bash** скриптом

```
root=$(cat wp-config.php | ?)
passs=$(cat wp-config.php | ?)

echo ${root}
echo ${passs}
```

как это сделать при том что данные *root* *passs* могут быть разными

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так:

```sh
root="$(sed -e "s/.*define( 'DB_USER', '\(.*\)' );.*/\1/p" -n wp-config.php)"
pass="$(sed -e "s/.*define( 'DB_PASSWORD', '\(.*\)' );.*/\1/p" -n wp-config.php)"

echo "$root"
echo "$passs"
```

Отучайтесь все команды начинать с `cat`'а.

Comment: Персональное спасибо за последнее предложение! Кстати, а разве в PHP нельзя как в Pythone сделать загрузку скрипта *как библиотеки*, а потом просто выдать данные? Был бы очень простой и понятный скрипт на PHP. Да, PHP умеет быть просто консольным скриптом, кто не знал, не для @Ainar-G :-)